# I need to throw a JSON Exception from a SOAP Webservice

Tags: json

I am new to JSON but I did some SOAP WebServices in the past.

My latest c#-WebService ("*.asmx") is used by different clients:
- a c# WebApp uses the SOAP Classes and SOAP Methods
- a Javascript talks to the WebService with ajax/JSON
- an Android App talks to the WebService with JSON

The c# WebApp gets all the Exceptions correctly
but the JSON clients get the Exceptions wrong - no matter
if the WebService throws an SoapException or if it throws
a WebException - all the JSON clients get is `Internal Server Error`.

```
[ScriptService]
[WebService(Namespace = "http://SvcAssessment/";)]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
public class SvcVideoAssessment : adpWebService
[
 // Implementation is here ...

 [WebMethod] [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
 public Call NewCall(string ticket, string name, Case cas, char status)
 {
  // generate an exception for testing
  throw new WebException("no new calls available");
 }

}
```

I would like to throw different type of Exceptions if I could
distinguish by any means whether the current Method-Call
came from a Script or whether it came from a SOAP client.

The JSON clients need to know what error
has occurred, the Error-Message `Internal Server Error`
is insufficient and misleading.

Comment: there is no such 'JSON Exception' thing. please tell more about what you want to do.

Comment: Hi Jiang!
I want to throw an Exception("abcd") in a c# Webservice Method.
And when the ajax/JSON Schript calls the Webservice Method
with try/catch it should get the Error message "abcd".
I want nothing more - I only want the right Error message.

Comment: this is not possible:"And when the ajax/JSON Schript calls the Webservice Method with try/catch it should get the Error message "abcd"." why you think  a server side C# exception can be convert to client side JavaScript exception.

Answer (score 2):

you need to do 2 things:

1.) Throw new Exception() rather than new WebException()

2.) add to web.config in configuration section:
    `<system.web>`
     `<customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>`
    `</system.web>`

then will your ajax/JSON client see the original Exception Messages